# Compiling and linking fortran code with MakeFile using Intel compiler

Tags: makefile, intel, fortran90

I have a code that is about 8,000 lines and is contained in the same one big bigcode.f90 file. It compiles without problems from the command line with intel compiler with the options:

```
mpif90  bigcode.f90 -r8 -O2 -xHost -override-limits -o output.out
```

I want to split this large file into modules and link them using makefile. Below I am listing the makefile. (So here I have main.f90, and also 8 modules linked to it, such as modparams.o and other 7). So I just broke the bigcode.f90 into 9 files. The problem is that when I compile with the makefile, it complains about things like

1. subroutine ended with "end" statement instead of "end subroutine"
2. integer passed to reals
3. some name conflicts between variable names and subroutine names.

All these may well be bad style. However the original bigcode.f90 had all of these, and it did not prevent it from compiling at all. I want to first replicate the results between the bigcode.f90 and the split version - and then I will make other changes.

I also made a copy of this makefile without any OBJECTS to link (just the single bigcode.f90), and that also compiled without any complains. Could somebody help me understand why is there inconsistency about what the compiler complains when there is one file versus when there are several linked files?

```
# DEFAULT FLAGS
CFLAGS := -I$(CPATH) -I$(F90_MODULES_PATH) 
F90 := mpif90

# ADD ALL LIBRARIES HERE (with -l$LIBRARY_NAME)
LDFLAGS :=  -llapack -v 


# ADD ALL SOURCE FILES HERE (with .o extension)
OBJECTS := modparams.o 
OBJECTS += modleeplex.o 
OBJECTS += modutilsmain.o
OBJECTS += modecon.o
OBJECTS += modindirect.o
OBJECTS += modijutils.o
OBJECTS += modselectstata.o
OBJECTS += modfcn.o


# ADD ADDITIONAL COMPILER FLAGS HERE
CFLAGS += -fbounds-check
CFLAGS += -ffree-line-length-350
CFLAGS += -r8 
CFLAGS += -O2 
CFLAGS += -xHost 
CFLAGS += -override-limits

# ADD ADDITIONAL MODULE FOLDERS HERE (with -I$PATH_TO_FOLDER)
F90_MODULES += -I.

all: main

main: main.f90 $(OBJECTS)
    $(F90) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $< -o $@ 

%.o : %.f90
    $(F90) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(F90_MODULES) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) *.mod
```

When I compile, I get the following, and then a long list of errors.

```
      mpif90 -c modfcn.f90 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/include:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/tbb/include:/opt/intel/composer_xe_20                                     13.5.192/mkl/include:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/tbb/include -I  -fbounds-check -ffree-line-length-350 -r8  -O2  -xHost  -override-lim                                     its -I. -llapack -v  -o modfcn.o
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-ffree-line-length-350'
ifort: command line remark #10010: option '-pthread' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See '-help deprecated'
ifort version 13.1.3
```

Comment: Post the compilation line that make generates for one of the objects.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the post. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Start by separating the include paths into multiple `-I` flags, I can't speak for openmpi but you cannot define multiple paths separated with `:` in gcc.

Comment: **1)** Before you can do something with Make, you must know how to do it *without* Make. Try to compile/build from the command line, and get that to work perfectly, before you attempt to write the makefile. **2)** Small steps. Try splitting off one module, and get that to work perfectly, before you attempt *eight*.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried what you suggest. Even if I split it into two parts only - still there this puzzle. The complete one bigfile - compiles both with the command line and with the make file. However if I split it, and even if I do a very watered-down version - compiler complains about the types of things I mentioned. Even though the bigfile also had those "issues" - but it compiles without any problem.

Comment: Also, I separated multiple -I flags. But I still have the issue. Also, if I compile one bigfile.f90 with a modified version of this makefile (where modification is to remove OBJECTS and have "bigfile.f90" instead of "main.f90") - it compiles, without complaints

Comment: Sounds like a Fortran question rather than a Make question. See if you can piece together an [mcve] and post it as a new question. (Maybe delete this question entirely; though please be aware that *repeatedly* deleting may have adverse effects on your reputation on Stack Overflow.)